# .Net 2.0 & SQL Server 2008 Hanging Process

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, threadpool

I created a simple .Net web service which runs a very simple query (which should normally be very quick). The query is something like this:

```
SELECT v.email 
FROM dbo.Reporting r 
INNER JOIN dbo.Reporting_EmailList el ON r.reportID = el.reportID 
INNER JOIN OtherDB.dbo.V_ActiveDir v ON el.userGUID = v.objectGUID 
WHERE r.reportID = @reportID
```

V_ActiveDir is a view for active directory data. This query essentially gets me a list of email addresses in which the report should be emailed out to. My Reporting table currently only has 3 records. I was trying to add fields to the Reporting table but it was taking forever, which is how I found out that this query was hanging in a sql process. Earlier in the day this script generated the following error:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion 
of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

... which explains the hanging process I think. We tried to kill it but now its in a rollback state and I think we may have to reboot sql server (which in my mind is weird that a select query would try to rollback). Is there any way with either sql server or .net to prevent this from occuring again? Or a way I can remove this process in sql... is it possible something is hanging in the thread pool? I can still select from the Reporting table so theres no table lock, only when I try to alter this table does it just spin its wheels.

I don't have much experience with IIS as I don't have access to it, but if there is a suggestions I can pass it along.

Edit: could this be cause because in my catch statement I don't check to see if the SqlConnection is open, and if it is close it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, NEVER reboot SQL if it is in a recovery state (e.g. the rollback you describe above).

ASP.NET queries normally time out at 30 or 60 seconds.

Check if the following fields are indexed:

- dbo.Reporting.ReportID,
- dbo.Reporting_EmailList.ReportID
- dbo.Reporting_EmailList.userGUID
- OtherDB.dbo.V_ActiveDir.objectGUID (in the underlying table)

Where is the OtherDB located? Is it a linked database? This could be part of the problem.

What does the query plan look like for this query? Can you see anything suspect there?